# Does Doomcaller think my C'Thun is dead if I have multiple and only one is dead?

Tags: hearthstone

Doomcaller is a card in the new Whispers of the Old Gods expansion, that reads *"Give your C'Thun +2/+2 (wherever it is). If it's dead, shuffle it into your deck."*.

This is a scenario that I will probably encounter soon: I play my C'Thun. It dies. My opponent plays C'Thun as well. I cast Entomb on it, which shuffles his C'Thun into my deck. Now I have a dead C'Thun, and another one in my deck.

If I play Doomcaller now, will it shuffle the dead one into my deck?

(similar situations occur with other cards, e.g. cards that make copies of C'Thun before it dies)

Comment: From what the wiki says, the battlecry will work in this situation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, it will work.

Doomcaller just checks if C'Thun is dead, without caring about the presence of any other copy in your deck or hand.

A reddit user had a [similar experience](https://www.reddit.com/r/hearthstone/comments/4gjgda/whispers_of_the_old_gods_faq/d2j59ve) to the one you explained in your question: he got a C'Thun from [A light in the darkness](http://media-hearth.cursecdn.com/avatars/289/467/35237.png), played it and it subsequently died. After played a Doomcaller he got a second copy of C'Thun added to his deck.

Comment: What if you have 2 dead C'Thun's, will it shuffle both back in or choose one (i.e. the first one it reaches)

Comment: @nickson104 honestly I don't know and I don't have a Doomcaller to do some testing. I'll try to find further informations.

Comment: I have the same problem, else I would test too. I just felt it would be a good addition to the answer

Comment: I have just tested this in a dungeon run. If two C'thuns are dead and you play a Doomcaller, _one_ C'thun will be added to your deck.